# Error 524: A Timeout Occurred (What It Is & How to Fix It)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, connection, timeout

I am using Cloudflare Hositng is a content delivery network that acts as a gateway between a user and a website server. When the 524 A timeout occurred status code is received, it implies that a successful HTTP Connection was made between Cloudflare and the origin server, however the HTTP Connection timed out before the HTTP request was completed. Cloudflare typically waits 100 seconds for an HTTP response and returns this HTTP status code if nothing is received. How can i fix error 524 connection time out.

I am Renerate SSL/TLS Certificate but it's not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to increase CloudFlare time-out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536167/is-it-possible-to-increase-cloudflare-time-out)