# Cloudflare proxy behavior on (client aborting request)

Tags: apache, cloudflare

I have a website with cloudflare proxy enabled in the DNS, so requests are going through cloudflare. There's a problem that when the user aborts a long loading/waiting request, cloudflare proxy doesn't abort it as well.

It's obvious when there's a stress loading on the server, I keep getting requests even after the test has finished.

Is there a way to deal with this issue from apache configurations or from cloudflare settings ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and enable [`mod_reqtimeout`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html) in Apache to set a timeout for request headers and bodies. That helps in disconnecting lingering connections.

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
    RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>
```

That would set a timeout for headers and bodies, with a minimum rate, to make sure slow requests are terminated.

This is similar to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77086456/6309) which mentioned:

> Note that if you are seeing Cloudflare's 504 errors prematurely after only 60 seconds (and you expected it to be only after 100 seconds), it's probably your Nginx configuration that, by default, only waits for 60 seconds for the upstream to respond.

(you are using Apache in your case, but the idea remains the same)